# What are the benefits of using log4cxx over plain syslog()?

Tags: logging, syslog, log4cxx

I've had log4cxx recommended to me as a good way of generating log messages from C++ applications.  However, plain old UNIX `syslog()` calls do let me output to files, or over the network, and have all the usual DEBUG/INFO/WARN/ERROR levels.

log4cxx is clearly more modular/customizable, but I really just want to log to a file so can't imagine needing to write any custom output functionality.  I feel like I must be missing something: what does log4cxx give me over and above using plain syslog?  Performance?  Robustness?  Portability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portability.

If one day you chose to move your application to a windows environment or somewhere else that doesn't provide syslog(), you won't have to rewrite your logger.

Answer (score 2):

It gives you the dubious joy of reinventing a wheel.  I've seen the light, and I'm shining it.  Unix works better. Syslog().

Comment: Would you care to expand on what it is about syslog that you prefer, and how it compares to log4xx in the areas that matter to you?

Comment: Portability is one thing I suppose. log4XXXXX is pretty much a standard API across languages, but I live in unix, and I would say why add a layer to logging?  If you can't think of anything syslog is missing, and I can't think of anything, then why not use syslog?